# Packages broken after accidentally deleted python3

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg, python3

I accidently deleted my python3 package and then I'm trying to reinstall the package. But I am running into errors everytime.

```
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 devscripts : Depends: python3 but it is not installable
              Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
              Recommends: dput but it is not installable or
                          dupload but it is not installable
              Recommends: python3-debian (>= 0.1.15) but it is not installable
 dh-python : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 gnome-orca : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
              Depends: python3 but it is not installable
              Depends: python3-brlapi but it is not installable
              Depends: gir1.2-wnck-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
 indicator-cpufreq : Depends: python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~) but it is not installable
                     Depends: gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 but it is not installable
                     Depends: libcpufreq0 but it is not installable
 language-selector-common : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
                            Depends: python3 but it is not installable
 lsb-release : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
               Depends: python3 but it is not installable
 onboard : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but it is not installable
           Depends: python3 (>= 3.4~) but it is not installable
           Depends: python3-gi-cairo but it is not installable
           Recommends: gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 but it is not installable
           Recommends: gir1.2-atspi-2.0 but it is not installable
           Recommends: onboard-data (>= 0.99.0~alpha1~tr1531) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-apport : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: apport but it is not installable
 python3-apt : Depends: python3 (>= 3.4~) but it is not installable
               Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but it is not installable
 python3-aptdaemon : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
                     Recommends: aptdaemon but it is not installable
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.4~) but it is not installable
                 Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but it is not installable
 python3-chardet : Depends: python3 but it is not installable
                   Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-commandnotfound : Depends: command-not-found-data but it is not installable
                           Depends: python3-gdbm but it is not installable
                           Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-crypto : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but it is not installable
                  Depends: python3 (>= 3.4~) but it is not installable
 python3-dbus : Depends: python3 (>= 3.4~) but it is not installable
                Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but it is not installable
 python3-dbus.mainloop.qt : Depends: python3 (>= 3.4~) but it is not installable
                            Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but it is not installable
 python3-defer : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-distupgrade : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-gi : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but it is not installable
              Depends: python3 (>= 3.4~) but it is not installable
 python3-httplib2 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-louis : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
                 Depends: liblouis2 (>= 2.5.3-2ubuntu1) but it is not installable
 python3-magic : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-notify2 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.1.3-13~) but it is not installable
 python3-oauthlib : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-oneconf : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
                   Depends: oneconf-common but it is not installable
 python3-piston-mini-client : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-pkg-resources : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.4) but it is not installable
                         Depends: python3:any (< 3.5) but it is not installable
 python3-problem-report : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-pyatspi : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
                   Depends: gir1.2-atspi-2.0 (>= 2.1.4) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libgail-common but it is not installable
 python3-pycurl : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but it is not installable
                  Depends: python3 (>= 3.4~) but it is not installable
 python3-pyqt4 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.4~) but it is not installable
                 Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but it is not installable
 python3-setuptools : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.4) but it is not installable
                      Depends: python3:any (< 3.5) but it is not installable
 python3-sip : Depends: python3 (>= 3.4~) but it is not installable
               Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but it is not installable
 python3-six : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-software-properties : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
                               Depends: python3 but it is not installable
                               Depends: unattended-upgrades but it is not going to be installed
 python3-speechd : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
                   Depends: python3 but it is not installable
 python3-update-manager : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-xdg : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 python3-xkit : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 scudcloud : Depends: python3 but it is not installable
             Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
             Recommends: fonts-lato but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: gir1.2-unity-5.0 but it is not installable
             Recommends: libqtwebkit-qupzillaplugins but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: python3-hunspell but it is not installable
             Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not installable
 software-center-aptdaemon-plugins : Depends: python-piston-mini-client but it is not installable
 software-properties-common : Depends: python3 but it is not installable
                              Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 software-properties-gtk : Depends: python3 but it is not installable
                           Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
 ubuntu-drivers-common : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
                         Depends: python3 but it is not installable
 ufw : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
       Depends: python3 but it is not installable
 update-manager : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
                  Depends: python3 but it is not installable
                  Depends: update-manager-core (= 1:0.196.14+elementary3~ubuntu0.3.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: update-notifier but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried `apt-get -f install` and got output as :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  gir1.2-wnck-3.0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-wnck-3.0
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  devscripts dh-python gnome-orca indicator-cpufreq language-selector-common
  lsb-release onboard python3-apport python3-apt python3-aptdaemon
  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-cairo
  python3-chardet python3-commandnotfound python3-crypto python3-dbus
  python3-dbus.mainloop.qt python3-defer python3-distupgrade python3-gi
  python3-httplib2 python3-louis python3-magic python3-notify2
  python3-oauthlib python3-oneconf python3-piston-mini-client
  python3-pkg-resources python3-problem-report python3-pyatspi python3-pycurl
  python3-pyqt4 python3-setuptools python3-sip python3-six
  python3-software-properties python3-speechd python3-update-manager
  python3-xdg python3-xkit scudcloud software-center-aptdaemon-plugins
  software-properties-common software-properties-gtk ubuntu-drivers-common ufw
  update-manager
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-wnck-3.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 48 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
48 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 70.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 43.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu/ trusty/main gir1.2-wnck-3.0 amd64 3.14.0-1~14.04~ricotz1 [70.4 kB]
Fetched 70.4 kB in 1s (55.1 kB/s)          
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.4' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.4-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 514978 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing devscripts (2.14.1ubuntu0.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/devscripts.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/devscripts.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package devscripts (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/devscripts.postinst: 739: /var/lib/dpkg/info/devscripts.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Removing dh-python (1.20140128-1ubuntu8.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/dh-python.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/dh-python.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing gnome-orca (3.10.3-0ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gnome-orca.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/gnome-orca.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package gnome-orca (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing indicator-cpufreq (0.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/indicator-cpufreq.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/indicator-cpufreq.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package indicator-cpufreq (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing language-selector-common (0.129.3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-common.prerm: 18: /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-common.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package language-selector-common (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing software-properties-gtk (0.92.37.7) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-gtk.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-gtk.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package software-properties-gtk (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing software-properties-common (0.92.37.7) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-software-properties (0.92.37.7) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-software-properties (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-apport (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.21) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apport.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apport.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-apport (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing lsb-release (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6.1+elementary6~ubuntu0.3.2.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/lsb-release.prerm: 18: /var/lib/dpkg/info/lsb-release.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package lsb-release (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing onboard (1.0.1-0ubuntu1+elementary7~ubuntu0.3.2.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/onboard.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/onboard.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package onboard (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing ubuntu-drivers-common (1:0.2.91.11) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-drivers-common.prerm: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-drivers-common.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-drivers-common (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-commandnotfound (0.3ubuntu12) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-commandnotfound.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-commandnotfound.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-commandnotfound (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-apt (0.9.3.5+elementary4~ubuntu0.3.2.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing update-manager (1:0.196.14+elementary3~ubuntu0.3.1.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/update-manager.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/update-manager.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat (1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-aptdaemon (1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-aptdaemon (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-cairo (1.10.0+dfsg-3ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-cairo.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-cairo.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-cairo (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-chardet (2.2.1-2~ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-chardet.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-chardet.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-chardet (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-oneconf (0.3.7.14.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-oneconf.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-oneconf.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-oneconf (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-piston-mini-client (0.7.5-0ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-piston-mini-client.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-piston-mini-client.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-piston-mini-client (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-oauthlib (0.6.1-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-oauthlib.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-oauthlib.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-oauthlib (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-crypto (2.6.1-4build1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-crypto.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-crypto.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-crypto (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing scudcloud (1.25-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/scudcloud.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/scudcloud.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package scudcloud (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-dbus.mainloop.qt (4.10.4+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-dbus.mainloop.qt.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-dbus.mainloop.qt.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-dbus.mainloop.qt (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-dbus (1.2.0-2build2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-dbus.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-dbus.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-dbus (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-defer (1.0.6-2build1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-defer.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-defer.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-defer (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-distupgrade (1:0.220.8+elementary4~ubuntu0.3.1.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-distupgrade.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-distupgrade.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-distupgrade (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-update-manager (1:0.196.14+elementary3~ubuntu0.3.1.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-update-manager.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-update-manager.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-update-manager (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing software-center-aptdaemon-plugins (0.1.6build1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/software-center-aptdaemon-plugins.prerm: 18: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-center-aptdaemon-plugins.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package software-center-aptdaemon-plugins (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-pyatspi (2.10.0+dfsg-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pyatspi.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pyatspi.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-pyatspi (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-gi (3.12.0-1ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-gi (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-httplib2 (0.8-2build1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-httplib2.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-httplib2.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-httplib2 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-louis (2.5.3-2ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-louis.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-louis.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-louis (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-magic (1:5.14-2ubuntu3.3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-magic.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-magic.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-magic (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-notify2 (0.3-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-notify2.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-notify2.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-notify2 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-setuptools (3.3-1ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-setuptools.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-setuptools.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-setuptools (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-pkg-resources (3.3-1ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pkg-resources.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pkg-resources.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-pkg-resources (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-problem-report (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.21) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-problem-report (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-pycurl (7.19.3-0ubuntu3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pycurl.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pycurl.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-pycurl (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-pyqt4 (4.10.4+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pyqt4.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pyqt4.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-pyqt4 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-sip (4.15.5-1build1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-sip.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-sip.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-sip (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-six (1.5.2-1ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-six.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-six.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-six (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-speechd (0.8-5ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-speechd.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-speechd.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-speechd (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-xdg (0.25-4) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-xdg.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-xdg.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-xdg (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing python3-xkit (0.5.0ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-xkit.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-xkit.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-xkit (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing ufw (0.34~rc-0ubuntu2) ...
Skip stopping firewall: ufw (not enabled)
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ufw.prerm: 15: /var/lib/dpkg/info/ufw.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package ufw (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 devscripts
 dh-python
 gnome-orca
 indicator-cpufreq
 language-selector-common
 software-properties-gtk
 software-properties-common
 python3-software-properties
 python3-apport
 lsb-release
 onboard
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 python3-commandnotfound
 python3-apt
 update-manager
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
 python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
 python3-aptdaemon
 python3-cairo
 python3-chardet
 python3-oneconf
 python3-piston-mini-client
 python3-oauthlib
 python3-crypto
 scudcloud
 python3-dbus.mainloop.qt
 python3-dbus
 python3-defer
 python3-distupgrade
 python3-update-manager
 software-center-aptdaemon-plugins
 python3-pyatspi
 python3-gi
 python3-httplib2
 python3-louis
 python3-magic
 python3-notify2
 python3-setuptools
 python3-pkg-resources
 python3-problem-report
 python3-pycurl
 python3-pyqt4
 python3-sip
 python3-six
 python3-speechd
 python3-xdg
 python3-xkit
 ufw
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

On terminal type: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.4`

That will fix your problem, if this does not help install it using:

`dpkg -i {The full name of python 3.4 package deb file}`

Comment: It didn't help much. Had to compile python3.4 from source. And reinstalled many broken packages. Thanks anyway.